# Where to know the situation of Adobe Air CSS support?

Tags: air, adobe

I wanted to gray my images, but I found it doesn't work when I set the `img` tag a CSS style `filter: grayscale(10%)`.

Does Air support `filter: grayscale(10%)` or `-webkit-filter: grayscale(10%)`?

Is there any post tells what CSS property does Air support?

Answer (score 0):

set the `UIComponent.blendMode` or `GraphicElement.blendMode` property to `"luminosity"` on the image or graphic.

This method works by blending the colours in the image with the color "behind" the image (usually the background color of the parent container or application).

So if the color behind the image is white or light gray, then the image will become gray. If the color behind is green, then the image will be colourized to green